# Django templates and views parsing forms

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

```
<form action="" method="post" id='editing_form'>{% csrf_token %}
            <label for='first_name'> First name: </label>
            <input type='text' id='first_name' value='{{user.first_name}}'/> <br/>
            <label for='first_name'> Last name: </label>
            <input type='text' id='last_name' value='{{user.last_name}}'/> <br/>
            <label for='first_name'> Email: </label>
            <input type='text' id='email' value='{{user.email}}'/> <br/>

            {% for key,value in prefs.items %}
                <label for='prefs_{{ key }}'> {{ key }}: </label>
                <input type='text' name = 'prefs' id='prefs_{{ key }}' value='{{value}}'/> <br/>
            {% endfor %}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I want to get values and ids of this inputs from my view

```
{% for key,value in prefs.items %}
                <label for='prefs_{{ key }}'> {{ key }}: </label>
                <input type='text' name = 'prefs' id='prefs_{{ key }}' value='{{value}}'/> <br/>
{% endfor %}
```

how can I do it?

P.S. I'm not allowed to use forms.

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will change you prefs in to `pre_`

```
[........]

{% for key,value in prefs.items %}
    <label for='pre_{{ key }}'> {{ key }}: </label>
    <input type='text' name = 'pre_{{ key }}' 
        id='pre_{{ key }}' value='{{value}}'/> <br/>
{% endfor %}

[.........]
```

To get the values and ids

```
def view_name(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        for val in request.POST:
            if val[0:4] == "pre_":
                id = int(val[4:])
                value = request.POST[val]

                #do save action here

    [..........]
```